# Consecutive Distance Rating

Tags: code-golf, array, integer

We'll call the consecutive distance rating of an integer sequence the sum of the distances between consecutive integers. Consider `2 9 3 6 8 1`.

```
2 9 3 6 8 1
<----5---->
<-2->
  <--3-->
```

\$2\$ and \$1\$ are consecutive integers, and their distance apart in the sequence is \$5\$.
\$2\$ and \$3\$ are consecutive integers, and their distance apart in the sequence is \$2\$.
\$9\$ and \$8\$ are consecutive integers, and their distance apart in the sequence is \$3\$.
The consecutive distance rating is the sum of these distances: \$10\$.

### Challenge

Given a possibly empty list of positive, **unique** integers, find its consecutive distance rating.

### Format

You must accept a list of integers and output an integer in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

### Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes (in each language) wins.

### Test cases

```
[] -> 0
[33] -> 0
[65 57 78 32 81 19 50 24 85 3 97 43 10 73] -> 0
[1 2] -> 1
[2 1] -> 1
[1 2 3] -> 2
[1 3 2] -> 3
[31 63 53 56 96 62 73 25 54 55 64] -> 26
[54 64 52 39 36 98 32 87 95 12 40 79 41 13 53 35 48 42 33 75] -> 67
[94 66 18 57 58 54 93 53 19 16 55 22 51 8 67 20 17 56 21 59] -> 107
```

Comment: What about something like `3 2 2`?

Comment: @Ausername The input will only consist of unique integers.

Comment: will the input contain only positive integers?

Comment: @Wasif "Given a possibly empty list of **positive**, unique integers, find its consecutive distance rating." [my emphasis]

Comment: Can we ouput `undefined` instead of `0` for the empty array?

Comment: ... or, alteratively, nothing at all, or `Nan`?

Comment: @Shaggy I'm going to say no, because the output format has been an integer from the beginning, and other languages may have had to compromise in bytes to satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 60 bytes

```python
lambda l:sum(abs(l.index(x)-l.index(x+(x+1in l)))for x in l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9bbsIwEPzPKeaPWAWU9dtI6UXSqgoliEjGRCEUevp0kxTklTW7Hs/Mdr/D6ZLkeCw/xlif94cacXe9nfN6f83jtk2H5pE/xOYF37ioTYhCiOOlxwNzM95PbWxAuwxxnVCir@9fbepuQy621y62Q77C5h0rwYSy@akjq/dNF@vvhl9Waz6C31LZpiFPjLqeEY55FOv5Lss0Vp@TRpFVSj2RNTAOzkNJeAIFmAJSwxsoBAetQAXci0@QM6SskqAn5CkWipwa9U9S7ESwCobLIlhYyVqQbKphDKxePtms4oHlGesEKOYuiRyCAUlozhCgOeAspgy0h2aygjOzhnVZFVjDgvy0kvGTR5jpvBXZyU9KGIJnMmQBclMqSTBhWaRwfw)

Comment: There is a way of saving a few bytes by getting rid of the `if` ...

Comment: @ovs Ah, right, nice one

Comment: `1 in` -> `1in`

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
iⱮ‘aạ¥JS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4xSkVBDEX7WcVZwksyycxswVYQLC0slL8BO7FxC7YWdiL4sRDtdCXvbeSZ@UJIbuDm5N5eHw53@36zvb9t909X69fzz8vZ@b5@f6yfx@3h9eL3MfvlvhezEo43WseULsjAF7TSHWM0qiELzYqgRZE5mZvlbkIYnhWMIDSNaBIr7kQtKSJ1XgwsPf9vGsMRpSZ4UPPrCWJO7dQ0G83LyNtA@sznfTLHyZYRJSZfFRc60dAFaTOFCj7@AA)

-1 byte thanks to Unrelated String!

### How it Works

```
iⱮ‘aạ¥JS - Main link. Takes a list L on the left
  ‘      - Increment all elements in L
 Ɱ       - Over each incremented element:
i        -   Get its 1-based index in L, or 0 if not present
           Call this list of indices I
      J  - Indices of L; [1, 2, 3, ..., len(L)]
     ¥   - Last 2 links as a dyad f(I, J):
    ạ    -   Absolute difference, element wise, between I and J
   a     -   And; Where there are non-zeroes in I, replace the value with corresponding difference
       S - Sum
```

Comment: As much as I love to look at the `aaạ`, [I'm not sure you need the triple dyad there](https://tio.run/##JY4xSkVBDEX7WcVZwksyycxswVYQLC0slL8BO7FxC7YWdiL4sRDtdCXvbeSZ@UJIbuDm5N5eHw53@36zvb9t909X69fzz8vZ@b5@f6yfx@3h9eL3MfvlvhezEo43WseULsjAF7TSHWM0qiELzYqgRZE5mZvlbkIYnhWMIDSNaBIr7kQtKSJ1XgwsPf9vGsMRpSZ4UPPrCWJO7dQ0G83LyNtA@sznfTLHyZYRJSZfFRc60dAFaTOFCj7@AA), seeing as `IaJ` has the same pattern of zero/nonzero as `I`. (Funny bonus 8-byter: `iⱮ‘oJạJS`)

Comment: @UnrelatedString Aww, now I have to redo my whole explanation :P

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

```
[:+/&,|@(#\-/#\)*1=-/~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1Bb4JAFITv/opJN3F3FRberghsoCFt4qnpwat4UTFqoiSVQxuIf51upQcO7zDzvpm59C@KH5FbcHgIYd35Cu/rj1W/sfNg6nWFYKUfsFLOKPeDRy8nn28Kw1NktmDOb1VX@K2VZakg5hq7n6a6DyAxdVYFEw6YiYxJ@Xi1Z7UFHEhP0MP3rf7id1yr5lQf5KTan2pQiBxHaKQwWCIBDf5gcz5WxozVMkIUI05gNBICpYhC6AWSyDWlMRbmrzz@z9AzQ25orLWb638B)

Consider `f 2 9 3 6 8 1`:

- `-/~` Table of differences:

  ```
  0 _7 _1 _4 _6 1
  7  0  6  3  1 8
  1 _6  0 _3 _5 2
  4 _3  3  0 _2 5
  6 _1  5  2  0 7
  _1 _8 _2 _5 _7 0
  ```
- `1=` Where are they 1?

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 1
  0 0 0 0 1 0
  1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `|@(#\-/#\)` Table of absolute value of index differences:

  ```
  0 1 2 3 4 5
  1 0 1 2 3 4
  2 1 0 1 2 3
  3 2 1 0 1 2
  4 3 2 1 0 1
  5 4 3 2 1 0
  ```
- `*` Elementwise product of those tables:

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 5
  0 0 0 0 3 0
  2 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `[:+/&,` Sum of that table flattened:

  ```
  10
  ```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ãʒÆ}kÆÄO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY4xTgQxDEWvwgFeMbZjJ@7pOcBoCpAoEAUFNR3aA3AFzsAJpqPgSoMzu1KUxPb7/v/t/fHp5fn4@7k/9u/fr/3y8bpf9s@H41jXjbvVbN7heKcPTBmCJL6gjeEY2WmGLPSTFXQ@itwqbm27DkwIw@sEGYSWDi2DhjvRJlP/qLKkiRV2Ne6kI0orq6RVjnOPOW3QCja6T3mWPJAxQ/uYm/MkK7fEdFHFhUF0dEH6zKKC57b9Aw)

```python
ã          # all pairs of integers from the input
 ʒ }       # keep those where the following results in 1:
  Æ        #   reduce by subtraction
    k      # for each integer in each pair get the index in the input list
     Æ     # reduce each pair of indices by subtraction
      Ä    # take absolute value
       O   # sum all distances
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>88</s> 77 bytes

```
func[b][s: 0 forall b[s: s + absolute offset? b any[find head b 1 + b/1 b]]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBNboQwDIX3nOJptlVVnMT5mUV7h26jLGAgmpEYqIBZ9PTUobQTRYrtfHrP9tx322ffxVTl85Yf4yW2KS5n1MjT3AwD2pIteEHTLtPwWHtMOS/9@oEWzfgd823scO2bTnISrH0jtCktaROBvrlcpR4ryBGP/dH6CCyDHZyHVvAECuAaysAzNIKD0aAa7g8nqCNSoGcNz3/9T2iC1WC5FsHCKpGBEj8DZlhzYJJaqYhGgBbytxWHwCAFI@YBRjrbpTTDeBiBNRwfCkEULMiXSdgX/bDDMgzZ4qUUmOBhHVQNcqUjReCQqhS/5tu4It6noazv9Pp@Qi7b234A)

Uses [@xnor's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229732/75681) - don't forget to upvote it!

Comment: Is the `/:` an assign at index?

Comment: @Razetime No, it's just indexing using the word (think variable) `i`. You can't just use `b/i` because it would mean `select b 'i` and the block `b` doesn't have a word `i` inside itself.

Comment: @Razetime Assign at index is `b/1: value`. If the index is referred to by a word `idx`, we need to write `b/:idx: value`.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 45 bytes

```r
sum(abs(seq(a<-scan())-match(a+1,a)),na.rm=T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/NasMwEITvfYrBvUh0U7ySVj@QvkVeQDUONSROYjv0UPrsrhzclB5KQaBhNPPtapj32G6wv/bN1J161Wl8YGxy/8vVHR537TjhfcjnczvM4/Wo8uuoxvai8nazFJTWm2OemjeVn5iy1tTn5@H4stPz58NeNcpQIkueIrHWN2e9rF2FF5JAIZI1FJk4kdRkHEUpxRTIWeKawnecyazK3JHFo593uybGaZhOnWoPixrPh25SlWV4CynHI3l4g2BhBOIgAu8qqlBp/We/5HyJGtgEWxAR1iAGJAEbuBohwTH4NsMKXIQrYYsg/6FTQXtwhARIXDZKNwonsF@2MwbCiPABpgaH5Q@GIelOnr8A)

Merged solutions: mine and [@Dominic's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229751/55372).

---

Previous solution:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 48 bytes

```r
x=scan();`*`=match;sum(abs(x*x-(x+1)*x),na.rm=T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9basMwEEX/u4qL@yOlk@KRNHqQZhdZQNyQUEPiBNuhhtK1u3JwU/pRCgINV2fOjNrxgJclDtdm19fnRtUaH@h2VfMr1TUeN/uux3tbXS77dhzWE6P0arvYrk9Vv3tbddeTql47NSyGpRqeWC8GTU313J7WGz1@PhzUThlKZMlTJNb6lsyXtXPhhSRQiGQNRSZOJCUZR1FyYwrkLHFJ4RtnMnNl7sqc0c@7nYmub/tzrfbHqeoux7pXhWV4C8nHI3l4g2BhBOIgAu8KKlBo/Wd/5nxGDWyCzYoIaxADkoANXImQ4Bh8m2EFLsJl2CLIf@qU1R4cIQESp43SzcIJ7KftjIEwInyAKcFh@oNhSLqbxy8)

Comment: This can be [48](https://tio.run/##hY9basMwEEX/u4qL@yOlk@KRNHqQZhdZQNyQUEPiBNuhhtK1u3JwU/pRCgINV2fOjNrxgJclDtdm19fnRtUaH@h2VfMr1TUeN/uux3tbXS77dhzWE6P0arvYrk9Vv3tbddeTql47NSyGpRqeWC8GTU313J7WGz1@PhzUThlKZMlTJNb6lsyXtXPhhSRQiGQNRSZOJCUZR1FyYwrkLHFJ4RtnMnNl7sqc0c@7nYmub/tzrfbHqeoux7pXhWV4C8nHI3l4g2BhBOIgAu8KKlBo/Wd/5nxGDWyCzYoIaxADkoANXImQ4Bh8m2EFLsJl2CLIf@qU1R4cIQESp43SzcIJ7KftjIEwInyAKcFh@oNhSLqbxy8) as a full program, making it the same length as my answer. However, now when there's `\(x)` syntax in R 4.1, but not available on TIO, I'm not sure anymore, which format to prefer...

Comment: @Kirill I'll change it to the `scan` version, so the answers are comparable. Which format to prefer? I mainly post functions because I think it's easier to read that way and I mostly care about the internal algorithm not the wrapper or technicalities.

Comment: I [couldn't resist](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229751/95126) joining the competition...

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 47 bytes

```r
sum(abs(seq(a<-scan())-(b=match(a+1,a,0)))*!!b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/NasMwEITvfYqJe5HSDXglrX4gfYu@gGMcashfLYceSp/dlYOb0kMpCDSMZj7tDtMe2w3211M79ueT6jU@kNvm9MvVPR5fujzifWgul26Y8vWoml1WuXtTzXYzF5TWG7V7PjZj@6qaJ6aGaq31erXa6enzYa9aZSiRJU@RWOubs1zWLsILSaAQyRqKTJxIajKOopRiCuQscU3hO85kFmXuyOLRz7tdEnkcxnOvusOs8uXQj6qyDG8h5XgkD28QLIxAHETgXUUVqrLCX/2S8yVqYBNsQURYgxiQBGzgaoQEx@DbH1bgIlwJWwT5D50K2oMjJEDiPFG6UTiB/TydMRBGhA8wNTjMOxiGpDt5@gI) with test wrapper stolen from [pajonk's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229743/95126) stolen from [Kirill L's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229746/95126)

Comment: The test wrapper is actually by [@Kirill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229746/55372) ;-)

Comment: Then why not merge our solutions? [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY/NasMwEITvfYrBvUh0U7ySVj@QvkVeQDUONSROYjv0UPrsrhzclB5KQaBhNPPtapj32G6wv/bN1J161Wl8YGxy/8vVHR537TjhfcjnczvM4/Wo8uuoxvai8nazFJTWm2OemjeVn5iy1tTn5@H4stPz58NeNcpQIkueIrHWN2e9rF2FF5JAIZI1FJk4kdRkHEUpxRTIWeKawnecyazK3JHFo593uybGaZhOnWoPixrPh25SlWV4CynHI3l4g2BhBOIgAu8qqlBp/We/5HyJGtgEWxAR1iAGJAEbuBohwTH4NsMKXIQrYYsg/6FTQXtwhARIXDZKNwonsF@2MwbCiPABpgaH5Q@GIelOnr8A "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 60 bytes

```javascript
n=>n.map((e,i)=>z+=(j=n.indexOf(e+1))+1?j>i?j-i:i-j:0,z=0)|z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZHNcpswFIX3PMXZGcY2QRKSUDoii0637a4b4pmojpxCCXiAZBq3fXb3CmzPaHF19Z1zf9S4dzfuh/o4bbv@2Z8P9tzZsktf3TGO/aZObHla27ixXVp3z/73t0Ps1yxJ1uyhKeuHZlvf19vmPtucbJb8PZ33fTdOmPw4fXajH2HxVO2wLZFFlRDXSElIDV1AcBQMzEBm4DkKCQGjkQuwDPrGM/A5ZFHFwa4hZbEgPFzEBRJUiUEJSDoKRkFx8gKnojmkhMoXkYoqSijKkY@BIHbpSMNIMI6cejDIqcHZTEjkBXKCBbScPZSOKkMeCqwII8ki1DAzTlMxFepxDslQEAyegenQFWeQZhkk00/peGzrKV49dqvkU7Ts8Jf/@O7at3mHt33O/@Jb2BK@vaqCyyoh4U2SHvrhi9v/vKB/LpZuGNwH2fl319JTle3SwR9bt/fxHe5eNlhtZp9A961P2/4lPsSzKoG1Fl/fXn/4IUjZLoD/kvN/)

Comment: `(j=n.indexOf(e+1))+1` ~> `~(j=n.indexOf(e+1))`

Comment: `(j=n.indexOf(e+1))<i?~j&&i-j:j-i` is better still.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 48 bytes

```r
`?`=diff;sum(abs(?o<-order(x<-scan()))*!1<?x[o])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDdSsQwEIXvfYqKN4mcQifJ5Acr@xLeibBrt116Ybu0XVwQn71Oa1WEXExOznxzJsPcZGWeNZeumtq@U63OPrKxOnT/VN1md0/1OGXvw@F8rod5v9s/HtumeRgvb@rwOqpdX@b9cKwHdS3zpV9pre9vqdxdn/sXPX/eNKpSBgkWHhGktShtN9Un6VkvlbJ2KzyDA0KENYgESuACxiGytKcAZ0EFwo@dYLbKbOBVw9@7/XVYgrdgOR7JwxvBwMg8B2Z4t9nk6kURhiQW53eUgMQgAyfDE5wkW1GW4SKcmC0Cb4QkBA@KyyYcF35azbIM@WWWMWCSr/ABpgCFJZEhcNJ6/gI)

Comment: Wow, that's impressive! Great use of `order`!

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```ruby
->a{r=-1;a.sum{((a.index(a[r+=1]+1)||r)-r).abs}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsMgFESv8pdKVPpttZVgLyIuDG2gi5ZiCLQkObuZLIYH82bqPPzbGJu@l6VGzX0x0/xehCjm9Xk8f6Kk2kXOHct1rVJXacowbVv70phSuCjyXhHfFLkrchBdOIMIBwTeOUXWgqwIE4@pPUEdF2iL2oWc2w4)

Thanks @ovs for -2 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 15 bytes

```
sᶠ{↻h₂-ȧ1&b}ˢcl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU87CsJAEL3KYGG1grPfbKMHCSmMhRYBQQsRsbEI2HkEsbG10UIvIHiK5CLxjUmK2fm99@Ztvp7Nl7titdDNfjug0YQG22ld3uvjsXqdDtXj3Gyq52Vfl@8lZqPPjYf54XudF02Tppmi1Bh5vVPkgqKQKDJaUcKKOGI2VqQteuyNogiIRWaMw58InJYMDvc9oF1puq1B7dE4CQ8dhNeiAYCcxgmH7K2gpfMyESWYMMLojcFBBJJRW3GBvRWznbrBzgJrhYs@OFGMoggVTtpvuqS9GTuWfJV960GD6aAIiAdU4wiH1rbG2MUs@wE)

```
sᶠ                 Find every substring of the input.
  {        }ˢ      Keep only those for which
       ȧ           the absolute value of
      -            the difference of
   ↻h₂             the first and last elements
        1          is 1,
         &b        and remove their first elements.
             c     Concatenate them,
              l    and output their combined length.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <strike>63</strike> 55 bytes

Inspired by the answer of xnor

Improved version, thanks @MarcMush:

```julia
!x=sum(abs,[(I=indexin)(i,x)-I(i+(i+1∈x),x) for i=x])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBLasMwFFzXp3gJWUhUgepre@HucwbjRUpSUEnVkNigI@ScvYg7L1ZIQULvjWbmjfQ1neJe53le5e46fYv9x1X1YtfFdDjmmKSIKsvtTsRXLP17u2UJgD5/LhS7PMg5pvM0Ukf9Lo39oCo@rC1F8Ip8rahuFFmjqNGKdAvsTZFx6HFvFbWgOJwacP3QgmpKCaX@h0Lz7OyTZtEG9J53gC12MGwJDifBRI8zuCJgIDDIlohlWfSIikwtyBq141y4dxy/DLC4c@A61qKvfTFt2RRGulne7ptlcluE/H4dliQGYg9TUAKoBnN0vYQ3gH07VEN1/2uKie5fXb2cLzGNpyTWm0jbd9qIlYhSrmV1TIf5Dw)

First version:

```julia
!x=sum(abs.([indexin(i,x)-indexin(i+(i+1 in x),x) for i in x]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBLbsIwFFw3p3ggFrYwVf1NvKD7niHKggqQXFGDIJFy@3QeMVAplj3jmXnj/AyntNPjNC3G7W34Fbvv27toU94fxpRFUqPcPMEan6aUaZTg6Xi@UrrDTsop5cvQ05bar9y3nap4s7Ycglfka0V1o8gaRY1WpCO4D0XGAePeKoqQOOwadP3wQmrKEU79j4XnhexLZgEDsOcVEIsVDEdCw00w0WMPrhiYCExyJGpZNj2qolOEWOPsuBfuHdcvAyzuHLSOvcC1L6GRQxGkm/ntvpknx2Lk9@swNzEwe4RCEiA1mKPrubwB7WNXddXzf99/dfV2uabcn7JYrhJtPmklFiJJuZTVIe@nPw)

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##TVBLasMwFFzXp3gJWUhUgepre@HucwbjRUpSUEnVkNigI@ScvYg7L1ZIQULvjWbmjfQ1neJe53le5e46fYt@/3EVYtfFdDjmmKSIKsvtTsRXLP17u2UJQNLnz4Vilwc5x3SeRuqo36WxH1TFh7WlCF6RrxXVjSJrFDVakW6BvSkyDj3uraIWFIdTA64fWlBNKaHU/1Bonp190izagN7zDrDFDoYtweEkmOhxBlcEDAQG2RKxLIseUZGpBVmjdpwL947jlwEWdw5cx1r0tS@mLZvCSDfL232zTG6LkN@vw5LEQOxhCkoA1WCOrpfwBrBvh2qo7n9NMdH9q6uX8yWm8ZTEehNp@04bsRJRyrWsjukw/wE "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: -2 bytes by using `*` instead of `I` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBLbsIwFFw3p3ggFjE1Uv1NvEj3PQPKggqQXFEXQSL5CJyzF0nnESMq2Xq/mXljf42nuFN5mha5u47f9e7zKrf1mrqY9occk6jjK476vd2ykFls4jrT8edCscu9mGI6jwN1tP1Iw7aXFQdjSuKdJNdIalpJRktqlSQV0HuTpC1qzI2kAIhFVGg3Dy6guqRgqn9dcJ6VecIMSo/a8fWQxfWaJYFhJ9joEL0tBG54brIkbBkmPazCUwBYIbfsC3PL9ssCg5kF1jIXdeOKaGBRCKl2frtr582hEPn9ys9ONMgOooB4QDX2qGY2r9F2oa/66v7XFBPdv7p6OV9iGk6pXq4ibd5pVS/qKMRSVIe0n/4A "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 13 bytes

```
›vḟv›ƛ&›[¥ε|0
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%E2%80%BAv%E1%B8%9Fv%E2%80%BA%C6%9B%26%E2%80%BA%5B%C2%A5%CE%B5%7C0&inputs=%5B2%2C9%2C3%2C6%2C8%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

A port of the jelly answer, and I think the best I'm gonna get.

### Attempted port of Jonas,  21 bytes

```
Ẋƛ÷ε1=;?Lɾƛ?Lɾ-ȧ;f*∑½
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%BA%8A%C6%9B%C3%B7%CE%B51%3D%3B%3FL%C9%BE%C6%9B%3FL%C9%BE-%C8%A7%3Bf*%E2%88%91%C2%BD&inputs=%5B2%2C9%2C3%2C6%2C8%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

### Old version, 23 bytes

```
L²(⁰Ẋni÷ε1=[n6ḋ÷ε&+])¥½
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=L%C2%B2%28%E2%81%B0%E1%BA%8Ani%C3%B7%CE%B51%3D%5Bn6%E1%B8%8B%C3%B7%CE%B5%26%2B%5D%29%C2%A5%C2%BD&inputs=%5B2%2C9%2C3%2C6%2C8%2C1%5D&header=&footer=) I still think there's a bit more I can do.

### Older version, 28 bytes

```
L(x|L(←x i⁰niε1=[n←xε&+]))¥½
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=L%28x%7CL%28%E2%86%90x%20i%E2%81%B0ni%CE%B51%3D%5Bn%E2%86%90x%CE%B5%26%2B%5D%29%29%C2%A5%C2%BD&inputs=%5B2%2C9%2C3%2C6%2C8%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

This. Is. Horrible.

Comment: Porting jelly somehow could save bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
Ｉ↨¹Ｅθ↔↨¹⁻⌕Ａθ⊕ικ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvNCsIwEIRfJcctRLAm6Q@eqiB4KAgeSw@xDRhMU21SXz9OXfjYGWZmeOplmLVL6bZYH@msQ6T7OlGr3/ThrHmE2a3R0EkHQ631a6CL9WPj3BZf/bCYyfhoRrJZxtkL5Nn/jil1nZKcFUAdOBM1KDirK3z4qoRW6EPLPWclcpnDC/SBQCbRldsWvlR9n3Zf9wM) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    θ           Input array
   Ｅ            Map over elements
             ι  Current value
            ⊕   Incremented
         ⌕Ａ     Find all (i.e. at most one) matches
           θ    In input array
        ⁻       Vectorised subtract
              κ Current index
      ↨¹        Take the sum
     ↔          Take the absolute value
 ↨¹             Take the sum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Note that base 1 conversion is used to sum as this works on empty lists.

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 129 bytes

```
func[a][s: 0
b: sort copy a
while[b/2][s: s + either b/2 - b/1 = 1[absolute(index? find a b/2)- index? find a b/1][0]b: next b]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLasMwELznK@bYUkK9klYPQ@k/9Gp0sB2FGIIdbIemX@@u3FPtgJDQ7MzO7I7ptHylUxUP7dBPqS2xnO99W9WxmkoUh6bENIwz2uH2g/rwfemuqWre1Vqe8IbUzZc0QiAc5SZ8gKq6mYbrfU4vXX9Kj0@c5UWdSa9HbDGKVRHFp0@PGU2c4nIbuz5b5kCQaP//Wm8Ry2AH56EVPIECuIAy8AyN4GA0qIDb6QhqCynQExaeSPVerAlWg@VYBAurxBNKwhkww5otX3ArJWkfoEXyN4BDYJCCkcgBRuZZe2qG8TBC1nC8bRWklQX5vAj22TGsKtkF2eyuFJjgYR1UAXI5oyJw2G9AwsAKleLyCw)

sorts the array, and adds the index difference to `s` if pair of elements has an absolute difference of 1.

Not sure how to shorten the reuse of `index? find`, but I think it can be shortened. `abs` alias for `absolute` is not available, even in version 0.6.4.

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 52 bytes

```
=LET(x,A:A,SUM(IFERROR(ABS(ROW(x)-XMATCH(x-1,x)),)))
```

Input numbers in column A. For each number x in column A look for x-1.  If found add the difference in rows between x and x-1.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
tQ!=&f-|s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyRQ0VYtTbem@P//aCMFSwVjBTMFCwXDWAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JY49agNBDEZ7n@K5cRdYSSPNqHDnCwTSLQanSRVXdpm7bzS7MAiNeN/P8/v9uz229@f5evn5@Httt69tvZ9WsxrheKcPTBmCJL6gjeEY2WmGLPSJClpTkWPnuNl@NSEMrxdkEFoStLwb7kQrpNaoX@kSK@qI7KQjSquQpFWD3cacNmgFG91LnaUOZMy2PqZv7mAVlpgZqrgwiI4uSJ9NVPC8/wM).

#### How it works

Consider input `[2 9 3 6 8 1]` as an example.

```
tQ   % Implicit input. Duplicate, add 1; element-wise
     % STACK: [2 9 3 6 8 1], [3 10 4 7 9 2]
!    % Transpose
     % STACK: [2 9 3 6 8 1], [3; 10; 4; 7; 9; 2]
=    % Test for equality (element-wise with broadcast)
     % STACK: [0 0 1 0 0 0;
               0 0 0 0 0 0;
               0 0 0 0 0 0;
               0 0 0 0 0 0;
               0 1 0 0 0 0;
               1 0 0 0 0 0]
&f   % Two-output find: row and column indices of nonzeros
     % STACK: [6; 5; 1], [1; 2; 3]
-|   % Minus, absolute value (element-wise)
     % STACK: [5; 3; 2]
s    % Sum. Implicit display
     % STACK: 10
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mx`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>16</s> <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Inspired by [xnor's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229732/58974).

```
VaWbU+WøUÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW14&code=VmFXYlUrV/hVxA&input=WzMxIDYzIDUzIDU2IDk2IDYyIDczIDI1IDU0IDU1IDY0XQ)

```
VaWbU+WøUÄ     :Implicit map of each U at 0-based index V in input array W
Va             :Absolute difference of V and
  Wb           :  Index in W of
    U+Wø       :    U + Does W contain
        UÄ     :      U+1
               :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 91 bytes

```python
def f(l):c=sorted(l);return sum(abs(l.index(x)-l.index(y))for x,y in zip(c,c[1:])if y-x==1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczNCgIhEADgV5njDMwG7kLUhk@y7KH8IcFU1AXt5a0O3b7Tl3p9xrAML7eZr7zwmS8s9qGNBYueViVLzNXor2/Z1CMHKMcL74@C/uSCNg0bTX92IhszNO7gArxdQsVqE@tOzkKfmpSCRsouVPztND4)

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##FcxLCsMgEADQq7icgUnBBEpq8QA5Q8ii9UMFq6IGtJe37e6tXur1FcOypjy83Ge60UJXWokfQxvLLHgUSpaYq9E/37OpZw6snG94PAvAJqS/uKBNQ2g4bdARbcysUWcusI9LoEjtXBzoLOtTk5LjSNmFCv8cxxc) by switching to Python 3.8.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>20 17</s> 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ã_ÎaZo)¥1©ZÊ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=41/OYVpvKaUxqVrK&input=WzMxIDYzIDUzIDU2IDk2IDYyIDczIDI1IDU0IDU1IDY0XQ)

- saved 5 thanks to @Shaggy!

```
    ã_  - subsections passed trough
    ÎaZo) * abs difference of 1st
            and last element(then removed)
    ¥1    * == 1?
    ©ZÊ   * take lenght/else 0
    -x flag to sum
```

Comment: [15 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4yB4X85hWswgpTGpWsrJ&input=WzMxIDYzIDUzIDU2IDk2IDYyIDczIDI1IDU0IDU1IDY0XQ), or [14 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=4yCuzmFazCClMalaysk&input=WzMxIDYzIDUzIDU2IDk2IDYyIDczIDI1IDU0IDU1IDY0XQ) with the `-x` flag.

Comment: [13 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=4yCuzmFabymlMalayg&input=WzMxIDYzIDUzIDU2IDk2IDYyIDczIDI1IDU0IDU1IDY0XQ)

Comment: [12 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=41/OYVpvKaUxqVrK&input=WzMxIDYzIDUzIDU2IDk2IDYyIDczIDI1IDU0IDU1IDY0XQ); always forget `A.ã()` can take a function. I hate that I've just outgolfed myself!

Comment: @Shaggy great! Didn't notice A.o removed the element, that's why it gave me wrong result!

Comment: `A.o()`, without an argument, is the same as `.pop()` in JS.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 42 bytes

```
Tr@Abs[s@@@Outer[s=#-#2&,#,#]~Position~1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU3NCoMwGLv7GgVPEey/HhzdE0zYbuKhE8d6UMF2J9FX73QTQkLyfSGDDe9@sMF1Nr6q@JjN9ekbb4y5fUI/N74iGWEpCEi71ZN3wU3jRts01rMbQ0Oyy8uQNt3unR23JVlWJAvnBysJqaELcIaCgpaQOZhAIcFRaggOmkP/finYIQz0dDhj/j9wCsUhdyiUCortPbB9QEBKKLEma/wC)

Essentially a port of [Jonah's J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229738/81203).

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 54 bytes

```javascript
$=([o,...a])=>o?a.indexOf(o+1)+a.indexOf(o-1)+2+$(a):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDRaoNAEHzvVyySB00u4ql3aooJfSkUCv2AEMiRamoIXog2LYR8u52tqU2E45zZndnZ25mTaTbH6tBOT2lX5t0od5dW@L5vVl4@twvjV/V78f1WunYivckNnAKGk5FrvFnQlZ/1pq1sTW3RtK4RdKy2H61H5wfCt7F105Kpm6/iSDmV0DwOBbsv/L3duuvl6Gz8na1q1yHHu6xoOqe1uMrEIM/z3pwW5BxM0zg0I2c8puenl1cajx1YXx5@YyxXggLAHkTRHdRKkEoEJamgKBSUSkEyAxcICmNg1CNBGVpi3BJ0cu8AQQhCDgRc5B3BHXABF95yEdMgo/9sYDVoxUdjKo4OeSJaOSgCKdw6Zi896JjXXOMxCB@x9m8hJM@gkfiPOT3qMS95nROhFqM3Zi1wouCtk8E7Y2/4ybR/KJX2ObKrnh9L6j5XCA8F75QdADFOJv0qIWiV8bME8O5@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 24 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 19.75 bytes

```
2zPgAu-1=keez0AhEeAuADES
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhY7jKoC0h1LdQ1ts1NTqwwcM1xTHUsdXVyDIdJQVQvWRhvpWOoY65jpWOgYxkIEAQ)

##### Explanation

```python
2zP       # All pairs in the input
   g      # Filtered by:
    Au-   #  Does the difference
       1= #  Equal 1?
k         # End filter
 e        # Map over the list:
  e       #  Map over the pair
   z0Ah   #   Get the index in the input
       E  # End both maps
e         # Map over this list:
 AuAD     #  Get the absolute difference
     E    # End map
      S   # Sum this list
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 122 bytes

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVPNjtMwEJY49ilGFQdbuFWd_xRSiQMHJBYkVpyqHrypsxuUJlXiQmHVJ-GyHODCE8Fj8AR8ttsVlD240_lm5vtmRpMv34dSNSr8sRxP2u6j6tvx6tej393Ve10aulB1S7cjorWuaAOHqf56mNPzvleflpemr9vrFZ_Tu7Y2VLhMog-qobUyCsCrejDMgUTMOVzQjIt_oDB8AExiQXEqKM0EhYGgTAqSObCZoCCCj3goKEdKBCsBpw_xoCwALM_gwEH_wTYbvNwVnUdCTxWet49QglhsX4KW8JLAtoN8OwW6jWGTyNImZ9U2mtgMq4v5QstwmhnD5aiU-B_ZARGP7B6OaiFiEXIjWws_jaGQpGcKuVUAq8z8RuPM95QfWexWZeJ7DMAUQyGzPHAhKlM_VgA4zu3OZil3AnzkTNX1xFgDKUF6v8XZ6DWnZxN3A_x4E_4qej3sGnsoOLly1yijXR0_pmxxTqZp2TB-6xLn9NhXCHpxJAZ00hC4TlPeALk98Rb3DRzGnvQwsm_k5e9V5341y5etWRUL_HIqvu1MNcl-fm6KRTOtkHWhtmxvnbpd6_2biu2fsLpizbTsWoNPYQAgOZekm0Hj7vjGtnNbKngTWSxed61-6ry6WFx2G83Q781UXQ3sL04-qTk_8Omw2_gOvh68vbvz9g8)

```scala
l=>l.flatMap(x=>l.indexOf(x+(if(l.contains(x+1))1 else 0))match{case -1=>None;case i=>Some(Math.abs(l.indexOf(x)-i))}).sum
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVNNi9swED30ll8xhB4kqoTI3w5NoYceCt0WuvQU9qBN5F0Xxw620qYs-SW97GVLof-ov6ZvZCeQdA9Gnjcz782Ip5-_upWpTPhnOZ7UzXfT1uObx6edKybZ3xe_m9uvduXoypQ1PYyI1ragDQJh2rtuTm_b1vxYXru2rO9u5Jy-1KWjha8k-mYqWhtnAHwoOyc8SCR8IBXNpDqDwvAZMIkVxamiNFMUBooyrUjnwGaKgggx8qGiHCURTg04fY4HbQFgfQEHHvoP5mrwSt90mQl7qvByfKQS5GL-EoyELwl4HNTzFpg2xplETJtcdHM24QrWxX4hMxx3xnI5OjX-I14Q-YjvYVALkYtQG3Ev4jSGQpJeKOSsAFad9TcaZ_1M-cDCt6qTfsYATDEUMuZBCFGd9msFgOOc72yWSi8gR_4ompaEqCClyO63sI1dS3o98R6Qgyd6V7S221VsFDhvtauMs75PDiVb2MlVtejGn33hnF72HYreDcSAjhoK7nSreyAPR97FaYDDuCc9jPgbDHyuOvfuXL6vHTsYx8nAnJ0WKLwyW7GnxZseKeu13X8qxP6VKAtPMV01tcOr6IBpKTXZqrOwoMRbwWin3QnSSEw0c31sanuOlwxfNxsrsNH91Nx24lxQ0oRKebymg5x2u41f7NA_2OHdPg7nPw)

```scala
def calculate(list: List[Int]): Int = {
  list
    .flatMap(x =>
      list.indexOf(x + (if (list.contains(x + 1)) 1 else 0)) match {
        case -1 => None
        case i  => Some(Math.abs(list.indexOf(x) - i))
      }
    )
    .sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
/+⌵/-⍉⊚=1⊞-.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__ZiDihpAgLyvijLUvLeKNieKKmj0x4oqeLS4KCmYgW10KZiBbMzNdCmYgWzY1IDU3IDc4IDMyIDgxIDE5IDUwIDI0IDg1IDMgOTcgNDMgMTAgNzNdCmYgWzEgMl0KZiBbMiAxXQpmIFsxIDIgM10KZiBbMSAzIDJdCmYgWzMxIDYzIDUzIDU2IDk2IDYyIDczIDI1IDU0IDU1IDY0XQpmIFs1NCA2NCA1MiAzOSAzNiA5OCAzMiA4NyA5NSAxMiA0MCA3OSA0MSAxMyA1MyAzNSA0OCA0MiAzMyA3NV0KZiBbOTQgNjYgMTggNTcgNTggNTQgOTMgNTMgMTkgMTYgNTUgMjIgNTEgOCA2NyAyMCAxNyA1NiAyMSA1OV0K)

```
/+⌵/-⍉⊚=1⊞-.
         ⊞-.  # difference table
      ⊚=1     # coordinates of ones
     ⍉        # transpose
  ⌵/-         # absolute difference of columns
/+            # sum
```